# how to join tables in blade file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I am failrly new to laravel and am building a simple app. I am using this function in my controller:

```
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }


public function index()
{

    //
    //return view('adminlte::home');
  //  $user= Auth::user()->id;
    $csafe = csafe::where('id','=', $user->id)->get()->first();
    return view('csaves.show', array('csafe' => $csafe));
}
```

but when I bring up the view in web browser I get the following error:

> Undefined variable: user
>   and only the query for users is shown to be run. 
>   "select * from `users` where `id` = '1' limit 1"
>   I also tried to use
>    $csafe = csafe::where('id','=', '{{$user->id}}')->get()->first();
>   this time it again fails erroring:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

and in my queries it shows:
"select * from `users` where `id` = '1' limit 1"
and 
"select * from `csaves` where `id` = '{{$user->id}}'"

what would be the best way to limit my csaves table to show the values for the specific user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the user variable $user is commented:

Change this:

```
//  $user= Auth::user()->id;
```

into:
    $user= Auth::user()->id;

Comment: I've already tried uncommenting it, in fact I made it commented by myself, when it is uncommented I get this error:
""Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found""

Comment: So you need to include it with 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
at the begin of your controller :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it in this way:

```
use App\User;
use App\Csafe;

public function index()
{

    $user = Auth::user();

    $csafe = Csafe::where('userid','=', $user->id)->first();
    return view('csaves.show', array('csafe' => $csafe));
}
```

As I can see your code,you are using some mistakes like:

1. you are not declaring $user variable
2. Not Calling and Using Csafe Controller
3. Using get() method and first() method at same time. Only any one of these can be used at a time.